# Comparing Integers in Java

Tags: java

I got the following code from a Java book that didn't have explanation about the results. I ran it and got the results noted below inline, but I need help understanding the results:

```
1. Integer i = -10;
2. Integer j = -10;
3. System.out.print(i==j);  //  ==> true
4. System.out.print(i.equals(j));   //  ==> true
5. Integer n = 128;
6. Integer m = 128;
7. System.out.print(n==m);  //  ==> false
8. System.out.print(n.equals(m));   //  ==> true
```

My questions are:

- why does line #3 resolve to true? are they not two separate objects?
- if line #3 is true, why does line #7 not true?

Thanks if advance.

Comment: Hint, integers in a specific range are cached ;) Have a look into the `Integer` class.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Thats the reason why should prefer Integer.valueOf(int) to new Integer(int)

Comment: But here's an interesting question:  Is it possible for #7 to ever be true?  The answer is YES, since the upper limit (but not lower limit) of the Integer cache is configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer` is an object, whereas `int` is a "scalar".  Something like `Integer i = 270;`, under the covers, becomes `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(270);`.  So when you create two `Integer` objects they are distinct (as demonstrated with `==`).

However, the JDK, in `valueOf`, caches the creation of `Integer` objects with a small value -- -128 to 127, and previous versions of those are reused if available.  So two apparently distinct instances of small `Integers` may actually be the same, although they appear to have been instantiated separately.

If you tried the same thing with `int` values the `==` compares would always be true, and the `equals()` calls would generate compile errors (because `int` isn't an object).

Answer (score 9):

See `Integer.valueOf(int i)` source code.

It caches (use integer pool) the Integers between -128 and 127 (those are the default values, which can be customized via `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high`)

Answer (score 2):

To emphasize the level of absurdity resulting from using `==` on Integers, consider this line:

```
Integer a = 200, b = 200;
System.out.println(a < b || a == b || a > b);
```

Apparently, this should print `true` regardless of values because it looks like a tautology. It prints `false`, of course. The following, apparently a tautology of the same kind, prints the expected `true` value:

```
System.out.println(a <= b || a > b);
```

Comment: great one! I really liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

### On question 1

According to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), a Integer class is wrapped around a primitive value, which simply means that you can expect the object to behave as a primitive when required (the comparison performed in Step. 3), and equally as an object when required (Step 4; this step isn't possible if **int** instead of an **Integer** class was used.). 
If you swap the types in Steps 1 and 2 to **String** instead of an Integer, and perform the tests again, you'll obtained the desired results you were hoping to get.

### On question 2

It has already been answered above: Integers in specific ranges (-128 and 127) are cached. 

 
Hope this helps.